# Mysql Select 1:n

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that relates 1:n

```
content
---------
- id
- title
- text

content_meta
-------------
- id
- content_id
- meta_key
- meta_value
```

A content can have multiple content_meta registers associated to it. Typically content_meta will contain the category, tags, descriptions and all that stuff, so I really don't know the number of registers a content will have.

What I want to accomplish is to take the content register and also all the related registers in content_meta in a single query.
I've tried the subselect approachment but seems that I can only get one register/column (¿?)
    SELECT content.*, (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM content_meta
                      WHERE content_id = content.id
                     )
     FROM content

This query complains that "Operand should contain 1 column(s)", so changing the '*' by for example `meta_key` clears the error, but returns a NULL for this subselect...

```
SELECT content.*, (
                  SELECT meta_key
                  FROM content_meta
                  WHERE content_id = content.id
                 )
 FROM content
```

Can anybody show me where to go from here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT c.*,
       cm.*
  FROM CONTENT c
  JOIN CONTENT_META cm ON cm.content_id = c.id
```

That will only return CONTENT and related when there is a supporting record in the CONTENT_META table.  If it's possible for a CONTENT record to not have any CONTENT_META data, use a LEFT JOIN instead:

```
   SELECT c.*,
          cm.* --these columns will be null if there is no supporting data
     FROM CONTENT c
LEFT JOIN CONTENT_META cm ON cm.content_id = c.id
```

### Followup Question -

---

> it is now possible to group by content.id, but renaming the meta_key column with its own value and the value of this column the content of meta_value?

MySQL doesn't have PIVOT syntax - you have to use CASE statements:

```
  SELECT c.id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cm.meta_key = 'A' THEN cm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'A',
         MAX(CASE WHEN cm.meta_key = 'B' THEN cm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'B',
         MAX(CASE WHEN cm.meta_key = 'C' THEN cm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'C'
    FROM CONTENT c
    JOIN CONTENT_META cm ON cm.content_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

You'll have to specify the `meta_key` for each one you want to appear in the resultset.

Comment: wow, how could I miss that... ok, just curiosity... it is now possible to group by content.id, but renaming the meta_key column with its own value and the value of this column the content of meta_value??

Answer (score 1):

How about just doing a join on the content id column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM content
LEFT JOIN content_meta ON content.id = content_meta.content_id
```